# "create table as" using Laravel's eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I've got a dynamically created query object using Eloquent and would like to use that to create a table vs returning a collection using $query->get(); Does anyone know if it is possible to turn that query object into a "Create table as" statement? Running MySQL and Laravel 5.4.

Example, would like to take these results to create a new table vs returning result:

```
$response = $query->limit($perPage)->offset($offset)->orderBy($orderBy, $direction)->get();
```